# with transaction.atomic() not working for Azure SQL Database

Tags: django, azure-sql-database, django-pyodbc-azure

I use `django-pyodbc-azure` 2.1.0.0 for the connection with an Azure SQL database which works fine.

When I understand the documentation of `django-pyodbc-azure` correctly, transactions should be supported.

However, this code immediately updates the row. I would expect, that the row is updated after 20 seconds.

```
from django.db import transaction
from myapp.models import MyModel
import time

with transaction.atomic():
    MyModel.objects.filter(id=1).update(my_field='Test')
    time.sleep(20)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to specifiy certain settings on the Azure SQL database?

---

When I set `AUTOCOMMIT = False` in my database settings, then the following code will not update the row at all.

```
MyModel.objects.filter(id=1).update(my_field='Test')
time.sleep(20)
transaction.commit()
```

---

My current `settings.py`

```
'azure_reporting': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'reporting_db',
    'HOST': 'xxxxxx.database.windows.net',
    'PORT': '',
    'USER': 'xxxx@xxxxxx.database.windows.net',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx',

    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
    }
}
```

Comment: no error message?

Comment: Unfortunately not - no output at all in the Python shell

Comment: did you set the AUTOCOMMIT true?

Comment: @LeoYue - I really appreciate your help! 
In my settings I didn't set AUTOCOMMIT at all - the default should be `True` though. However, I just tried to set it to `False` in my settings. I edited the question so you can see the actions I further took.

Comment: If you set `AUTOCOMMIT = False` and the code will not update the row, I think the transactions  works well.

Comment: No error happend, it's hard to judge what is going wrong. We just can recheck the [Configuration](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure#configuration) of `django-pyodbc-azure`.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have set the `AUTOCOMMIT=true` on database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': 'yourserver.com',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'NAME': 'your_db',
        'USER': 'your_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'your_pw',
        'AUTOCOMMIT': True,

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',

        },
    },
}
```

No error happened, the only things what we can do is recheck the [configuration](https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure#configuration) of `django-pyodbc-azure`.

As you said: When I set AUTOCOMMIT = False in my database settings, then the following code will not update the row at all.

I think the transactions should works well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have exactly the same settings except that I'm using `'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'`.

In regards to `AUTOCOMMIT = False` - shouldn't the row be updated when I do a  `transaction.commit()` at the end?

Comment: @RaideR just try it. I think you need to test a lot,  maybe you can find the solution. I'm sorry that that's  all the help which I can give for you for now.